# Error in Shiny trying to convert variable to date format

Tags: r, date, shiny, typeconverter

I've trying this code to work inside server.R file in order to build up an app. Outside of shiny works fine but maybe it's something related to how shiny pass an input to one reactive method.

This my server.R file (part of it)

..............

```
dat2<-reactive({  fichero<-input$fichero

#Si el fichero que leemos no tiene nada devolvemos un Nulo

if (is.null(fichero))
  {return()}

# Leemos el fichero


salida<-read.csv(fichero$salidaapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,quote=input$quote,stringsAsFactors=input$stringAsFactors)
   if (input$miss==TRUE) {salida<-salida[complete.cases(salida),]}
   return(salida)

   if (input$fecha==TRUE) {
     if (is.numeric(input$columnscf))
     {
   origen<-sort(salida[,input$columnscf])[1]
   salida[,input$columnscf]<-as.salidae(salida[,input$columnscf,drop=FALSE],format="%d/%m/%Y",origin=origen)
 }
 else {origen<-sort(salida[,input$columnscf])[1] 
 salida[,input$columnscf]<-as.salidae(salida[,input$columnscf,drop=FALSE],format="%d/%m/%Y")}
 return(salida)


  }

     else {return(salida)}
   })



output$choose_columnscf <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$fichero)|| is.null(input$columns))
    {return()} 
    dat<-data()
    dat<-dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]
    dat<-as.data.frame(dat)
    dat<-dat[,varlist(dat,type=c("factor","numeric"))]
    dat<-as.data.frame(dat)
    colnames <- names(dat)

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    selectInput("columnscf", "Elija la variable categórica", 
                choices  = colnames)
  })
```

''''''''''''''

When I try to run my app i get this error 
ERROR do not how to convert 'dat[, input$columnscf, drop = FALSE]' to class “Date”